# Write to file in a loop cpp

Tags: c++, ostream

A general question of writing to files in a loop and outside a loop:

suppose I have the following code:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <string>
# include <fstream>
# include <sstream>

using namespace std;
void printToFile(string name, double **Array) 
{
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open(name);
    for (unsigned int m=0; m<5; m++)
    {
        for (unsigned int n=0; n<10; n++)
        {
            myfile << Array[m][n] << " ";
        }
    }
    myfile.close();
}

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    double **Arr;
    string str;
    ostringstream oss;

    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {           
        for (j=0; j<10; j++)
        {
            // some calculation that yields Arr with size [5][10]
            str="";
            oss << "Arr_j_"<<j+1<<"_i_"<<i+1<<".txt";
            str = oss.str();
            printToFile(str,Arr);
        } 
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

I can't seem to get the name of the files right, what I get is:

```
Arr_j_1_i_1.txtArr_j_2_i_1.txtArr... etc
```

Also, my code run finish but the output files stop at `i=2`, I would also appreciate comments about which steam to use (`ostream`,`fstream`,`sstream`, etc...)

Comment: Instead of `ofstream myfile; myfile.open(name);` use initialization: `ofstream myfile(name);`. And you don't need to explicitly close the file. The destructor does that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are never clearing out the `ostringstream` after each iteration.  To do that automatically for you, you can just move the `oss` declaration into the loop.  This way after each loop the stream will be destroyed and you will start with a fresh stream on the next iteration.

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++)
{           
    for (j=0; j<10; j++)
    {
        ostringstream oss;
        // some calculation that yields Arr with size [5][10]
        oss << "Arr_j_"<<j+1<<"_i_"<<i+1<<".txt";
        printToFile(oss.str(),Arr);
    } 
}
```

I also removed `str=""` and `str = oss.str();` as it is not needed.  You can just use `oss.str()` as a parameter to `printToFile` and get rid of `str`.

I am not sure if it would be faster or not but you could avoid using any type of stringstream and construct the string in the function call using [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to convert the indexes into strings.  that would look like

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++)
{           
    for (j=0; j<10; j++)
    {
        // some calculation that yields Arr with size [5][10]
        printToFile("Arr_j_" + std::to_string(j+1) + "_i_" + std::to_string(i+1) + ".txt", Arr);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

declare str and oss inside the loop, you are not clearing oss

```
  for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {           
        for (j=0; j<10; j++)
        {
            // some calculation that yields Arr with size [5][10]
            string str;
            ostringstream oss;
            oss << "Arr_j_"<<j+1<<"_i_"<<i+1<<".txt";
            str = oss.str();
            printToFile(str,Arr);
        } 
    }
```